# CS50 PSET 4 Filter "Blur" not passing all requirements

Tags: c, cs50

I have been working on the blur section of PSET 4: Filter (less-comfortable) and I finally got it to blur, but it didn't pass all the tests.

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    int blue = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int red = 0;
    int divisor = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
        {
            copy[row][column] = image[row][column];
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
        {
            // loop through "top left pixel" through "bottom right pixel" if current pixel is in middle
            for (int loopRow = row-1; loopRow <= row+1; loopRow++)
            {
                for (int loopCol = column-1; loopCol <= column+1; loopCol++)
                {
                    // checks if the "looping" pixel is within 1 row and column of blurring pixel
                    if (loopRow >= row-1 && loopCol >= column-1 && loopRow <= row+1 && loopCol <= column+1)
                    {
                        // checks if "looping" pixel's row or column is negative and that it is within width and height
                        if ((loopRow > -1) && (loopCol > -1) && (loopRow < height) && (loopCol < width))
                        {
                            // adds the "looping" pixel's red, green, and blue values and increments divisor
                            blue += copy[loopRow][loopCol].rgbtBlue;
                            green += copy[loopRow][loopCol].rgbtGreen;
                            red += copy[loopRow][loopCol].rgbtRed;
                            divisor++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // current pixel's colors are changed
            image[row][column].rgbtRed = round(red / divisor);
            image[row][column].rgbtGreen = round(green / divisor);
            image[row][column].rgbtBlue = round(blue / divisor);
            // reset color and divisor values
            blue = 0;
            green = 0;
            red = 0;
            divisor = 0;

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

These are the tests I'm not passing:

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "126 140 149\n"
:) blur correctly filters pixel on edge
:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
```

I was looking at the first "test" I didn't pass and it says `:( blur correctly filters middle pixel expected "127 140 149\n", not "126 140 149\n"` I noticed that I had 127 instead of 126, so it must've been really close. Also, the image produced is blurred, but I guess not exactly.

Here is the original image:
[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SD90.png)

Here is the blurred image:
[blurred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xBMR.png)

I just want to know what I did wrong since it's too tedious to use the debugger (looping through an image).

Comment: `red / divisor` is integer division. Try `red / (float)divisor` instead and for the other colors as well.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was just changing

```
image[row][column].rgbtRed = round(red / divisor);
image[row][column].rgbtGreen = round(green / divisor);
image[row][column].rgbtBlue = round(blue / divisor);
```

to

```
image[row][column].rgbtRed = round(red / (float) divisor);
image[row][column].rgbtGreen = round(green / (float) divisor);
image[row][column].rgbtBlue = round(blue / (float) divisor);
```